# How to use Globalize.js to change the date format that validation uses?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-globalization

I have the globalize.js file, and I want to force the dateformat to dd/mm/yyyy at a global level somewhere so then all jquery validation and datepicker etc. will pickup this dateformat.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did my answer help you out in the end?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following applied in your layout would suffice:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || Globalize.parseDate(value, "dd/MM/yyyy") !== null;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible for me to output the current format, and see if that your snippet changes it?

Comment: Refer to the Globalize documentation: https://github.com/jquery/globalize#core I believe this is referring to your other question.